# Threads with lambdas and runnable in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning Java and I've started writing some tasks. Could you give me feedback for it?

> Write a static method `andThen` that takes as parameters two Runnable instances
>    and returns a Runnable that runs the first, then the second. In the main method,
>    pass two lambda expressions into a call to `andThen` , and run the returned
>    instance.

```
public class Exercise7 {

    public static class Thread1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Echo from thread1");
        }
    }

    public static class Thread2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Echo from thread2");
        }
    }

    public static Runnable andThen(Runnable thread1, Runnable thread2) {

        return () -> {
            thread1.run();
            thread2.run();
        };

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Runnable thread1 = new Thread1();
        Runnable thread2 = new Thread2();

       andThen(thread1,thread2).run();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that `thread1` and `thread2` are "threads" in name only. There is no multithreading going on: all of your code is running on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution does what has been asked, however for some simple improvements I'd look at removing the duplicate code as the `Thread1` and `Thread2` classes only diff in their name.  So I'd delete one of the classes and pass a name parameter, now called `NamedThread`...

```
public static class NamedThread implements Runnable {
    private final String name;

    NamedThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Echo from " + name);
    }
}
```

We can also improve the solution to make it reusable and extendable, for example, say we wanted it to work for 3 threads. So `andThen` can accept any number of
`Runnable`s and call `run()` on each of then

```
public static Runnable andThen(Runnable... runnables) {
    return () -> Arrays.asList(runnables).forEach(Runnable::run);
}
```

We can then improve main and remove the local variables

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    andThen(new NamedThread("thread1"),
            new NamedThread("thread2")).run();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but neither the question nor your answer have anything to do with threads. In order to run two separate threads, you need to create a `Thread` object with your runnable, rather than just calling `myRunnable.run()`. The first runnable returns to the scope of your `main()` method before the second is executed, i.e. they are sequential and exist in a single thread.